# Why does my linked list code result in a Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, list

I wrote a quick generic linked list, simple stuff.  But I have a bug and I cannot spot what it is complaining about. Pertinent code:

```
typedef struct _node {
    void *data;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

typedef struct _queue {
    node *root;
    node *last;
    unsigned int length;
} queue;

node * find_node(void *data, int size, queue *q)
{
    node *n;

    for(n=q->root;n;n=n->next)
        if(memcmp(data, n->data, size)==0)
            return (n);

    return (NULL);
}
```

Testing it:

```
queue q = {NULL, NULL, 0};
node *n;
int data[QUEUEMAX];
int i;

/* insert bunch of ints into queue */
for(i=0;i<QUEUEMAX;i++) {
    data[i] = give_me_a_number();
    n = alloc_node();
    n->data = data[i];
    insert_into(n, &q);
}

printf("list size = %d.\n", q.length);

/* print out, make sure they're there */   
for(n=q.root;n;n=n->next)
    printf("data = %d\n", (int)n->data); //*(int *)n->data didn't work, segfault?

/* find a specific node */
node *nd = find_node(&data[10], sizeof(int), &q);
/* remove it */
rm_node(nd, &q);
```

Running it:

```
$ ./test
list size = 256.
data = 10
data = 11
data = 12
data = 13
data = 14
data = 15
data = 16
... blah blah (256 lines)
Segmentation Fault
```

gdb says the problem is the `memcmp()` in `find_node()`. I think gcc is whining about the `n->data` being passed to `memcmp()`.  Any ideas? Also, I was getting a segfault trying to do `int x = *(int *)n->data` but this seems valid to me, non?

Comment: How did you implement the `insert_into()` function? I suspect it doesn't set the last element in the list to point to NULL.

Comment: @pmg that may be a problem but his comment `//*(int *)n->data didn't work, segfault?` indicates that there is a direct problem with `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
n->data = data[i];
```

You are currently setting the `void* data` pointer to be `data[i]` but you really want to set it to the **address of** `data[i]` so you need to do:

```
n->data = &data[i];
```

That is also why you got a segfault on your cast.

Comment: Haha what a dumbo I am.  Thank you Graham.

Answer (score 0):

`Segmentation Fault` happens when you try to dereference NULL pointer. If you know the line where it happens verify that there no `NULL` there, example `int x = *(int *)n->data` will generate `SEGFAULT` if n is `NULL` or `n->data` is `NULL`

Comment: Its actually not NULL in this case. Its just not pointing to a valid memory location because its an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your memory allocation functions are working, most likely n->data is NULL, and therefore you can't access it. Also, why are you passing the data array as &data[10]? Why not just use data since the identifier of an array is a pointer to its first location?

Comment: I'm passing data[10] for reason whatsoever.  Was just to test to remove a specific node from the list.  It finds the int stored in data[10] in the list, and gives me the corresponding node.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are being inconsistent in whether your `data` is a pointer or if its a pointer thats being casted to an `int`. You are passing a `int` (since the pointer is basically a `int` cause of the cast).

`memcpy` naturally wants a `void *`, not an `int`.

So the solution really is to pass a pointer to your `int` in data and make everything else work with that.

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of me forgetting the & when setting up the list in the test.  Which GrahamS spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the memcmp call in find_node will sometimes compare too much data. You're using memcmp with the size of the data you're searching for. If the data in the current node is shorter than that, memcmp will go beyond it, into forbidden territory. (The test code you posted won't usually trip this bug, because most of the data fields have the same length.) You need to add a length field to each node, and use the minimum of both lengths in memcmp.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning an int variable

```
n->data = data[i];
```

To what it is supposed to be a pointer

```
typedef struct _node {
void *data;
struct _node *next;
} node;
```